# SelectSingleNode with XML Namespace

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

My Xml as below

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
> <order xmlns="http://example.com/abc">
>     <class>
>       <about></about>
>     </class>
>     <dataset>
>        <subjects></subjects>
>     </dataset>
>  </order>
> ```

I tried to access node by below ways

> ```
>  XmlNode order = myXml.SelectSingleNode("order");
>  XmlNode subjects= order.SelectSingleNode("/order/dataset/subjects);
>  XmlNode dataset= myXml.SelectSingleNode("order/dataset");
> ```

Even I tried with Xml namespace manager as below

> ```
>   XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr= new XmlNamespaceManager(myXml.NameTable);
>   nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab","http://example.com/abc");
>   XmlNode order= myXml.SelectSingleNode("//ab:order", nsmgr);
>   XmlNode dataset= myXml.SelectSingleNode("//ab:order//ab:dataset",nsmgr);
> ```

Where I am doing wrong here? How to access node in this case. Please help me.

Comment: Your code used to work. If it doesn't work for you, please provide minimal but complete codes that demonstrate the problem : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @user1893874 This code will work., Kindly post if any `Exception` , you are getting.,